# Secretary: Parts 1-5

Tags: cipher, enigmatic-puzzle, knowledge, metapuzzles

<sup>An entry in [Fortnightly Topic Challenge #35: Restricted Title 1](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6352/48337)</sup>

---

My friend worked as a secretary, and she left out of nowhere! I found a few strange notes/messages scattered around her room.

## [Secretary: Part 1](https://xkcd.com/494/) (notepad on desk)

[image]

## [Secretary: Part 2](https://xkcd.com/495/) (carved on shelf)

```
266-7273
322-3265
328-2367
369-9464
```

## [Secretary: Part 3](https://xkcd.com/496/) (sticky note on laptop)

```
AFVNM;
FNKL;
```

## [Secretary: Part 4](https://xkcd.com/497/) (address book in drawer)

```
*AMP* FIR PMR
```

## [Secretary: Part 5](https://xkcd.com/498/) (notecard in cabinet)

```
af trem hel tranl homf
X houl *repl lf homl *ciaf tranf
```

---

Where specifically did my friend work, and what should we all be afraid of?

Comment: Part 1 is some kind of ROT13(fubegunaq).

Comment: I edited just now to fix a mistake in Part 3. It doesn't make a huge difference, so carry on.

Comment: To fit the Restricted Title challenge, should the title be changed to one of the xkcd titles?

Comment: @noedne I had the same concern myself before posting, so I asked it on [Sphinx's Lair](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/45063431#45063431). It doesn't seem people mind the technicality, as long as it satisfies the overall goal of a restricted title. I don't think any service is done if I renamed the puzzle "Secretary: Part 1", because then it wouldn't be completely accurate, as there are 5 parts.

Answer (score 3):

### Partial Part 1

The symbols are

> words in [Gregg shorthand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregg_shorthand).

My attempt at translation is

> help ask listening speak/speech thinking typing hat(e) foray,

with possible alternatives. Several of the words are clearly related, but I have been unable to find meaning in them.

Comment: This reminds me of gur Vagrearg, nf gurfr ner nyy guvatf gung gurl nyybj. "uryc nfx" nccyvrf gb frnepu ratvarf naq sbehzf, "yvfgravat" nccyvrf gb fgernzvat zhfvp, "fcrnx/fcrrpu" vf gur ibvpr argvmraf unir, "guvaxvat" - NV, "glcvat ungr" - boivbhf, "sbenl" - jub unfa'g tbar qbja gur enoovg ubyr ba Jvxvcrqvn?

Answer (score 2):

**Partial Part 2:**

The mechanism here seems to be that

> each number can spell out a word using a telephone keypad.

I think I have 3/4 of them:

> COMPARE
>  ??????? (possibly FACE-something? FACEBOOK with a missing O?)
>  ECUADOR
>  DOXXING

Comment: This seems to point to Jvxvyrnxf. Nffnatr vf va gur Rdhnqbevna Rzonffl, gur fvgr vf xabja sbe erirnyvat vqragvgvrf (Qbkkvat), naq vg jnf pnhtug hc va gur fbpvny zrqvn nffnhyg ba gur 2016 HF ryrpgvbaf nybat jvgu Snprobbx. "Pbzcner" vf yrff fgebat bs n pbeeryngvba.